# How to return raw query result in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

How to return the raw query result in django. Following is my code

```
join = Books.objects.raw({'$lookup':
            {
            'from': 'titles',
            'localField': 'title',
            'foreignField': 'title',
            'as': 'join_array'
            }})

return HttpResponse(join)
```

Comment: In what format do you want to return it?  json?  plain text?

Comment: in json format.

Comment: Use `JsonResponse` instead of `HttpResponse`. Import it from `django.http`.